# the request has a delay or request is delayed

Tags: word-usage

can I say: if the request **has a delay** when reaching the server, then it will not be processed by the service provider at the server side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you would utilize the passive voice to obscure the cause of the delay (which may be unknown) by saying,

> "If the request **is delayed** when reaching the server, then it will not be processed by the service provider at the server side." **[correct]**

In itself, "a request" generally cannot be responsible for its own delay, so you would **not** say,

> "If the request **has a delay** when reaching the server, then it will not be processed by the service provider at the server side. **[incorrect]**

Comment: Here's an [interesting ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=flight+is+delayed%2Cflight+has+a+delay&year_start=1970&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) that underscores your point.